Is it possible to track memory consumption on neo4j?
I have a query that dies after several hours because of memory consumption. I already addressed this question here: Neo4jError: db.memory.transaction.total.max threshold reached on AWS EC2 instance.
I also looked at the manual and around the net but I'm not finding how to track it. What I need is to know how much progress did the query do, before it throws the out of memory error
Neo4jError: The allocation of an extra 2.0 MiB would use more than the limit 56.0 GiB. Currently using 56.0 GiB. db.memory.transaction.total.max threshold reached


You need to learn how to do "profiling"; a query that runs > 10mins (or threshold limit) will be terminated by the system

You need to revisit your query and optimize it. that amount of RAM should accommodate queries handling petabytes sized data.
